# Does the parameter maximumPoolSize of WorkManagerThreadPool in jca-boss-beans.ml limit the maximum of threads we can instanciate?

Tags: jboss, jms, threadpool

I would like to know if the parameter maximumPoolSize on service WorkManagerThreadPool in jca-boss-beans.xml limit the maximum of threads we can instantiate ?

Thanks for your answers,

Nicolas Maujean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the maximum number of JCA connections that can be active at the same time (each connection is managed by a thread). So this property doesn't limit the overall number of threads JBoss is using, but just JCA connections. If you want more information about performance and pools you can check [Best Practices for Performance Tunning](http://www.jboss.com/pdf/JB_JEAP5_PerformanceTuning_wp_web.pd).